# Error with get_cart() method in woocommerce_order_item_meta_end hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I have this code, its function is to add a column in woocommerce order details email template, but when I send an invoice I get this error message saying:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null in http:\mysite.com\functions.php on line 1245

when using this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'order_custom_field_in_item_meta_end', 10, 4 );
function order_custom_field_in_item_meta_end( $item_id, $item, $order, $cart_item) {
    global $woocommerce;

    do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents' );

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

        if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
            echo '<td class="td">'.$_product->get_price_html().'</td>';
        }
    }

    do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents' );

}
```

[image: This is the result of the email template, I used a plugin called woocommerce email test]

My problem here, is that when I send an invoice or any other email notification from the order it gets an error.

What I am doing wrong and how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Please, tell me your line 1245 in function.php

Comment: @DhruvinMoradiya this is the line: foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

Comment: Can you please tell me what is your requirement?

Comment: actually the error only occur when I send an email invoice through order and its pointing to that line, i have used $product->get_cart() and its not working also

Comment: I just need to display the price per product on the email template, see image above

Comment: For get price of product you can use:$_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$_product->get_regular_price();
$_product->get_sale_price();
$_product->get_price();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136954/discussion-between-francis-alvin-tan-and-dhruvin-moradiya).

Comment: Hi, im still getting errors

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_regular_price() on boolean

Comment: Remove this code from this and use only following code: $_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );$_product->get_price();

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but you can't use **`WC()->cart`** object for the orders or emails as the cart is already processed in checkout and emptied. Instead you can use the variable arguments that your function has when hooked in **`woocommerce_order_item_meta_end`**, which are **`$item_id`**, **`$item`**, **`$order`** and **`$plain_text`**…

> **You don't need any foreach loop here** to get the **order items data** as you can use **directly `$item` argument** to get the ID of your product.

Here is the right code that will work with simple or variable products as well *(but see at the end)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'order_custom_field_in_item_meta_end', 10, 4 );
function order_custom_field_in_item_meta_end( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ) {

    do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents' );

    if( $item['variation_id'] > 0 ){
        $product = wc_get_product($item['variation_id']); // variable product
    } else {
        $product = wc_get_product($item['product_id']); // simple product 
    }

    // Be sure to have the corresponding "Cost each" column before using <td> tag
    echo '<td class="td">'.$product->get_price_html().'</td>';

    do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents' );

}
```

> You can't use a html **`<td>`** tag **if your "Cost each" column haven't been created (or defined) before**.

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the action *woocommerce_order_item_meta_end* is get triggered only after placing the order. so that the scope of the  **WC()->cart** is not exists inside your code snippet.

You can use **$order->get_items()** to get order items.

Please modify your code this way to make it work

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'order_custom_field_in_item_meta_end', 10, 4 );
function order_custom_field_in_item_meta_end( $item_id, $item, $order) {
    do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents' );

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // Do something here
    }

    do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents' );

}
```